# If $f$ is analytic in the unit circle and $ \int_0^{2\pi}{|f'(re^{it})|dt}\leq M $ I want to prove that $ \int_0^1{|f(x)|}$ converges

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, contour-integration

Here is the full formulation of the question:

> *Let $f(z)$ be analytic in the unit circle and $\int_0^{2\pi}{|f'(re^{it})|dt}\leq M$ for all $0 \leq r<1$. Prove that  $\int_0^1{|f(x)|dx}$ converges.*

My idea: since $f$ is analytic in the unit circle, $f'$ is analytic as well and both have Taylor series converging to them in the circle. Can be proven that $a_n$ coefficients of the series are bounded by something with $M$, but I'm having trouble with it and also tying this up with the real integral.

Thanks!

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1740114

Comment: It helps, but I'm looking to use the Taylor series, and I can't quite figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: In the proof given in the other thread, replace $f$ everywhere by its Taylor series, and there you go.